# iphone save multiple views screenshot

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an UIImagePickerController to which I add some subviews that contain images. I need to save the whole content as an image, but fail to do this.

For saving the content of the context i use the following code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It works for the UIImagePickerController but if i add subviews it stops at the

`[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

line, without any error in the console, just quits the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to grab everything on the screen in your screen shot, I found this on stack overflow:

```
UIWindow *screenWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenWindow.frame.size);
[screenWindow.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It will grab everything on the window.

Hope this helps.